# wrap_content doesn`t work with background

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

There is Frame Layout, where width\height = wrap_content. But it increases to max size when I try to set a background, even if it doesn't contains any elements.How to fix it?

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
   xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"; 
   android:background="@drawable/oblakol" 
   adroid:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
   android:layout_centerInParent="true" > 
    <TextView 
      android:id="@+id/textView8" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="TextView" />
 </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: It will take complete size of background image as you set it as wrap_content. size of FrameLayout is depended upon your background image size.

Answer (score 3):

Your background is much bigger than you think. Check size of background!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap content is working but your image size is large and hence you are not getting the expected results.
Try importing image as -> IMAGE ASSET so the size will be auto-Adjusted 
or
set size manually!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you ...

wrap_content will put the background of it's original size.

Using large resolutions will cause lagging in your app while using. So, you should resize your background according to your needs : [Image Resizer](https://fast-image-resizer.en.softonic.com/)

Answer (score 0):

When you set the dimensions(layout_width or layout_height) of a view to WRAP_CONTENT, you are giving freedom to the view to expand without any limit(as per its content ). Same is with your scenario as you've set the height and width to WRAP_CONTENT for your Frame Layout.

So whatever the space occupied on screen, its due to the large size of your **android:background="@drawable/oblakol"** drawable image. Try setting the height and width of the Frame Layout to some random values to test it.

```
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="250dp"
```

I've attached some screenshots for your reference.

1. android:layout_width and android:layout_height set to WRAP_CONTENT. Actual dimension of the android Image is 800x799(wxh)

[image]

2. android:layout_width and android:layout_height set to WRAP_CONTENT. Actual dimension of the android Image is 256x256(wxh)

[image]

3. android:layout_width and android:layout_height set to 250dp. Actual dimension of the android Image is 800x799(wxh)

   [image]

Hope it helps.